# Marshmallow(23) + RecyclerView(23.1.0) scrolling messes up content above after item removed (notifyItemRemoved)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-6.0-marshmallow

The `RecyclerView` messed up if build with `Marshmallow (Android 23)` .

I using `RecyclerView` filled with list of items and when swiped right will remove the item. Removing the item works fine. 
But scrolling up on the `RecyclerView` after removing an item, creates blank space on the item above the one removed.

I'm using the sample project here https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare with the latest android version (Marshmallow)

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.support.android.designlibdemo"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
 }
}
```

And add the swipe to dismiss code

```
private void setItemDismiss(final RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            ((SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter()).removeItemAt(position);
        }
    };

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
```

The adapter has the method `removeItemAt` to remove item

```
public void removeItemAt(int position) {
        mValues.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
```

Everything works good if `compileSdkVersion 22` and `targetSdkVersion 22` with `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0`

Check this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbiFzDzFwjo&feature=youtu.be

Let me know if anyone had this issue.

Comment: Can you include the call for `removeItemAt()`? Does it call [notifyItemRemoved()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRemoved(int))?

Comment: I am encountering this issue as well... Glad it's not just me. I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: Glat to know it'll be fixed soon. For now, If you change 'DefaultItemAnimator' with your own dummy class extending 'RecyclerView.ItemAnimator' the problem goes away, you get no animations though. mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator()

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered this issue as well.  It appears to be only a problem with support lib 23.1.0.  I do not encounter the problem using com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1.  I have submitted this bug to Google https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191960

Looks like the fix is on its way: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190500

Comment: i'm seeing same behavior  with 23.0.1 . Are you sure the targetSdkVersion  and compileSdkVersion are 23 ?

Comment: @Libin Yes, targetSdk and compileSdk are both 23.  There seems to be a dependency between the design lib and the recyclerview.  Make sure to set your design lib to 23.0.1 as well.  "compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'"

Comment: @GFed . Yes. It works with 23.0.1. Thanks . Please let me know if you hear back from google on the bug.

Comment: I'm still seeing this with 23.0.1

Comment: It has now been fixed as 23.1.1 is released